# Spinning a jpg in html 5 canvas or css3

Tags: animation, html5-canvas, android-animation, css-transitions

I'm quite a novice when it comes to animation on the web, and I was wondering if anyone knew how I could use a jpg to both stream an mp3 and constantly rotate when clicked. I asume it can be done with html5 canvas or css3 transitions? but I don't have a clue how to execute this  especially as i would want it to rotate slowly constantly, Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: you will need CSS3 animation, not transition.

Answer (score 0):

You could use css3's [animation](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_animations.asp) feature:

```
.spinning {
  animation-name: rotate;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

and just append the *spinning* class to every object you need to rotate. Just change the [animation-duration](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-duration.asp) properties in order to make the animation slower or faster. Note that you will have to add the vendor prefix '-moz', '-o', '-webkit' to every CSS3 properties. For example for FF you will need,

```
.spinning {
  -moz-animation-name: rotate;
  -moz-animation-duration: 5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
@-moz-keyframes rotate {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

.